# Change icon from not filled to filled in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to change favourite icon on my list when clicked.

**Icon before clicked**

[image]

**Icon after clicked**

[image]

When I click the first Icon when it's not filled in, I want to be able to change it and have it filled in.

I've tried a couple of things and it just doesn't seem to work, I know this is a simple task and I just don't want to waste any more time trying to figure it out. Has anyone got any suggestions on how to do this?

**What i've tried**

**Try 1:**

```
$(this).closest('a').next('i').remove();
$(this).closest('a').append("Appended the item");
```

**Try 2:**

```
$(this).closest('a').next('i').removeClass('glyphicon-star').addClass('glyphicon-star-empty');
```

**html**

```
<li>
   <a class="selectNavigationBTN active">
      <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw selectNavigationBTNIcon"></i> 
      <span class="selectNavigationBTNIcon">Server</span>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-star pull-right addToFavourite"></i>
   </a>
</li>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on('click', '.addToFavourite', function ()
{
    // Check to see what the text value is on the button
    var buttonValue = $(this).closest('a')[0].innerText;

    // Switch depending on the value of which button is clicked
    switch (buttonValue)
    {
    case " Server":
        // Save server link to favourites
        SaveToFavouriteLinkFile("serverBTNFav", "Server");
        $(this).closest('a').find('i.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-star').addClass('glyphicon-star-empty');
        break;
    case " Group":
        // Save group link to favourites
        SaveToFavouriteLinkFile("groupBTNFav", "Group");
        break;
    case " User":
        // Save user link to favourites
        SaveToFavouriteLinkFile("userBTNFav", "User");
        break;
    case " Sync":
        // Save sync link to favourites
        SaveToFavouriteLinkFile("syncBTNFav", "Sync");
        break;
    case " Patient Listing":
        // Save patient listing link to favourites
        SaveToFavouriteLinkFile("PatientListBTNFav", "Patient Listing");
        break;
    case " App Settings":
        // Save app settings link to favourites
        SaveToFavouriteLinkFile("AppSettingsBTNFav", "App Settings");
        break;
    case " Logging":
        // Save logging to favourites
        SaveToFavouriteLinkFile("LoggingBTNFav", "Logging");
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: @DipeshRana updated question to include the html

Comment: On which element is the click event handled? The line should be `$(this).closest('a').find('i.glyphicon-star')`

Comment: @ShaunakD i've updated my question to show the clicked event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The element `i` is inside `<a>` and not the *next* element(sibling) of `<a>`,

```
$(this).closest('a')
       .find('i.glyphicon')
       .removeClass('glyphicon-star')
       .addClass('glyphicon-star-empty');
```

If you need to toggle the icons on subsequent clicks, use:

```
$(this).closest('a')
       .find('i.glyphicon')
       .toggleClass('glyphicon-star glyphicon-star-empty');
```

---

**Edit (Answer)** :

If your click event is bound on `addToFavourite`

```
$(document).on('click', '.addToFavourite', function (){ 

    ...
    case " Server" :
        $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-star-empty').addClass('glyphicon-star');
        //or $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-star glyphicon-star-empty');
    ...
});
```

Comment: This seems to not be working, i've updated my question to show you how the code looks in the click event. It's got the code i'm using

Comment: Check the edit version in my answer above. It should work ideally. Can you elaborate what does not work?

Comment: The toggleClass works, but I don't want to toggle the class. I need the class to remain there until they need to remove it from the favourites list.

"$(this).closest('a')
       .find('i.glyphicon')
       .removeClass('glyphicon-star')
       .addClass('glyphicon-star-empty');" 

This line of code doesn't seem to fill the star

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).removeClass('glyphicon-star-empty').addClass('glyphicon-star');` inside `case "Server"`?

Comment: How the toggle works, I want it working like that. However I don't want it to be able to toggle off

Comment: Ohh, I think I got the issue. Check the updated answer. You were trying to add empty class instead of non-empty. Changed the order of remove and add. `$(this).removeClass('glyphicon-star-empty').addClass('glyphicon-star');`

Answer (score 0):

`.next` returns the immediately following sibling, but in your case , its not sibling , its child so use `.children` instead `.next`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(this).closest('a').children('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-star').addClass('glyphicon-star-empty');
```

Or if you want to make it simple add a click event on the addToFavourite and make it also toggle

```
$('.addToFavourite').click(function(){ 
    if($(this).hasClass('glyphicon-star')){
      $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-star').addCla‌​ss('glyphicon-star-empty'); 
    }else{
     $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-star-empty').addCla‌​ss('glyphicon-star'); 
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" with this

Comment: I'm trying to use this line "$(this).closest('a').children('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-star').addCla‌​ss('glyphicon-star-empty');" and it's giving the unexpected token

Comment: Write .addClass('glyphicon-star-empty') manually since when copied from code it adds some bullets